# Python 3.6.1 Update System (IDLE, console..)

Tags: python, python3

I have installed python3.6.1 I want to make it the default for the system when python is called. I also want IDLE to open to that version.

After installing python3.6.1:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

After running `alias python=python3` 
- python runs 3.5.2
- IDLE3 also runs 3.5.2

```
/usr/bin $ ls | grep python
dh_python2
dh_python3
idle-python2.7
idle-python3.5
python
python2
python2.7
python2.7-config
python2-config
python3
python3.5
python3.5m
python3m
python-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config
```

Comment: Do not change the system-provided python. Critical processes of your system rely upon the specific version of python.

Comment: Don't mess with the python. Many have been bitten severely who dared to upset it. No, seriously. Don't touch the system's python packages and don't try to make anything else the default for running `python` or `python3`. Many important things in Ubuntu are written in Python (e.g. the package manager `apt`) and they will break if you suddenly try to run them with a different interpreter.